# Выбор языка программирования в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Хочу научиться писать на Java. Скачал Android Studio, но при создании проекта мне не предлагают выбрать язык между Kotlin и Java, и просто создается проект на Kotlin.

Я читал, что их можно комбинировать, но я хотел бы выбрать Java при старте проекта.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Нет необходимости выбирать язык при создании проекта. Язык выбирается при создании файлов с исходным кодом.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy хорошо, но что все же стало с полем выбора языка? куда оно пропало, ни в каком источнике не видел чтобы его не было

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы создаете проект на Jetpack Compose. Эта штука работает только на языке Kotlin, поэтому невозможно выбрать язык Java.

Чтобы был возможен выбор языка программирования, создавайте проект **«Empty Views Activity»** или **«No Activity»** вместо «Empty Activity»:

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 0):

Для Андроида лучше выбрать Котлин, он куда проще, что касается вопроса, Compose новая штука, ровно как и Котлин и в соответствии с этим, Джава не будет поддерживать Джетпак. Создавай любой другой шаблон без приписки Compose и проблема должна быть решена. Java - XML. Kotlin - XML и Compose