# Отсутствует разметка activity_main.xml при создании нового проекта в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Нет папки `layout` и файла `activity_main.xml` в Android Studio при создании нового проекта. При создании использовал шаблон "Empty Activity".

Как создать эти файлы?

[image: Создал шаблон Empty Activity]

Comment: почему вы думаете, что должна быть такая папка?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-create-dice-roller-app-with-button?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-development-with-kotlin-4%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-training-create-dice-roller-app-with-button#2

смотрю этот курс

Comment: Там не сказано, что должна быть такая папка.

Comment: В новой версии Android Studio нужно использовать шаблон "Empty Views Activity", а не "Empty Activity", если не хотите использовать новомодный фреймворк [Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose). Вот тут уже была [похожая проблема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1514725).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Создание нового проекта в Android Studio Фламинго](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1518896/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-android-studio-%d0%a4%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%be)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте проект заново, вы создали проект на [Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose). При использовании этого фреймворка не подразумевается использование разметок в XML-формате, так как разметка создается из кода.

Чтобы создать обычный проект, используйте шаблон **«Empty Views Activity»**:

[image: создание нового проекта в android studio]